# Use Get Set Modifier And Function to change variable Value in C# MVC

Tags: c#

```
 public class ExaminationModel
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ExaminationId { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ExaminationName { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime ExaminationDate { get ; set; }

}
```

I want to convert the every ExaminationDate to  local time zone (local time zone is save in Database) how can i do that i tried some thing like

```
 [DataMember]
    public DateTime ExaminationDate
    {
        get { return ConvertToLocalDateTime(); }

        set { }
    }


  public DateTime ConvertToLocalDateTime()
        {

            string timezone = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["timezone"].ToString();
            TimeZoneInfo infotime = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezone);
            DateTime thisDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(ExaminationDate, infotime);

            return thisDate;
        }
```

I got an stcakoverflowexpection How could i do this what i am missing ? appreciate some help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are recursively calling ExaminationDate property. You could use a private variable instead like this below:

```
    private DateTime examinationDate;

    public DateTime ExaminationDate
    {
        get { return ConvertToLocalDateTime(examinationDate); }
        set { examinationDate = value; }
    }

    public DateTime ConvertToLocalDateTime(DateTime examinationDate)
    {

        string timezone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName;
        TimeZoneInfo infotime = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timezone);
        DateTime thisDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(examinationDate, infotime);
        return thisDate;
    }
```